# Convert antlrcpp::Any to std::string

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

I am writing translator from my grammar 'qwerty' to C++ target using Visitor pattern. Since base class `QwertyParserBaseVisitor` returns `antlrcpp::Any` type, derived class `QwertyParserBaseVisitorImpl` so does. But I would like to write translated program to file. How can I convert `antlrcpp::Any` to std::string?

```
    ANTLRInputStream input(in_stream);
    QwertyLexer lexer(&input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    QwertyParser parser(&tokens);
    QwertyParserBaseVisitorImpl visitor;

    // returns "My translated to cpp code" wrapped with antlrcpp::Any;
    antlrcpp::Any translated = visitor.visit(parser.program()); 
    std::cout << translated;

namespace AntlrQwerty {
    class QwertyParserBaseVisitorImpl : public QwertyParserBaseVisitor {
        antlrcpp::Any 
        AntlrQwerty::QwertyParserBaseVisitorImpl::visitProgram 
        (AntlrQwerty::QwertyParser::ProgramContext *ctx) {
            return "My translated to cpp code";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `antlrcpp::Any::get_typeinfo().name()`.

Comment: @Hamed, I have no method `get_typeinfo()`.
I've downloaded runtime from here:
[antlr4.7.1-runtime](http://www.antlr.org/download.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `template<class U> StorageType<U>& as()`. It works properly if U is an type of the variable you pass in constructor. In other words specifically

```
std::string hello("Hello, world");
antlrcpp::Any a(hello);
std::string string_value;
try {
    string_value = a.as<std::string>();
    std::cout << string_value << std::endl; // print "Hello, world"
} catch (std::bad_cast const& e){
    // failed to cast to string
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Didn't have a compiler to test. Drop ::value please.

Comment: What does `typeid(a.clone()).name()` give you?

Comment: Sorry, man. I am trying this from my phone. Have no compiler. OK. Did you try my edit from above? i.e. `<std::string*>`